# How do i resolve an HTTP500 Error while web scraping with Mechanize in ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to retrieve my driving license number, issue_date, and expiry_date from this website("https://sarathi.nic.in:8443/nrportal/sarathi/HomePage.jsp").  When I try to fetch it, I get the error `Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError for https://sarathi.nic.in:8443/nrportal/sarathi/DlDetRequest.jsp -- unhandled response`.

This is the code that I wrote to scrape:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.log = Logger.new "mech.log"
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari 4'
Mechanize.new.get("https://sarathi.nic.in:8443/nrportal/sarathi/HomePage.jsp")  

page=agent.get('https://sarathi.nic.in:8443/nrportal/sarathi/HomePage.jsp')  # opening home page.
page = agent.page.links.find { |l| l.text == 'Status of Licence' }.click         # click the link.
page.forms_with(:name=>"dlform").first.field_with(:name=>"dlform:DLNumber").value="TN3‌​8 20120001119" #user input to text field.
page.form_with(:name=>"dlform").field_with(:name=>"javax.faces.ViewState").value="SUBMIT"  #submit button value assigning.
page.form(:name=>"dlform",:action=>"/nrportal/sarathi/DlDetRequest.jsp") #to specify the form i need.
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
gg=agent.submit page.forms.last  #submitting my form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't working since you are clearing off the cookies before submitting the form, hence removing all the input data you provided. I could get it working by removing it simply as:

```
...

page.forms_with(:name=>"dlform").first.field_with(:name=>"dlform:DLNumber").value="TN3‌​8 20120001119" #user input to text field

form = page.form(:name=>"dlform",:action=>"/nrportal/sarathi/DlDetRequest.jsp")
gg = agent.submit form, form.buttons.first
```

Note that you do not need to set the value for #submit button, rather pass the submit button while form submission itself.

Comment: thank you sir, but one thing! how can i extract my DL no,Issue date,and expiry date from the output?

Comment: You can find it using the response of submitted form stored "gg". Though the number you provided didn't work for me, and came up as invalid trying from the UI, so just check it once.